# Confused as to how printf and strings are handled when disassembling a C program

Tags: c, assembly, x86, disassembly

I'm writing small C programs and disassembling them using objdump and gdb to see what the assembly looks like. I don't understand how functions like printf work on an assembly level. The C program I last compiled is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("test");
    return 0;
}
```

A gdb disassembly of the program produces the following:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00401460 <+0>:     push   ebp
   0x00401461 <+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
   0x00401463 <+3>:     and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x00401466 <+6>:     sub    esp,0x10
   0x00401469 <+9>:     call   0x4019c0 <__main>
   0x0040146e <+14>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x405064
   0x00401475 <+21>:    call   0x403a60 <printf>
   0x0040147a <+26>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0040147f <+31>:    leave
   0x00401480 <+32>:    ret
   0x00401481 <+33>:    nop
   0x00401482 <+34>:    nop
   0x00401483 <+35>:    nop
   0x00401484 <+36>:    xchg   ax,ax
   0x00401486 <+38>:    xchg   ax,ax
   0x00401488 <+40>:    xchg   ax,ax
   0x0040148a <+42>:    xchg   ax,ax
   0x0040148c <+44>:    xchg   ax,ax
   0x0040148e <+46>:    xchg   ax,ax
End of assembler dump.
```

I understand that the printf function is part of the standard C library, which is a precompiled DLL. However the string I'm passing to printf is not precompiled and should be found somewhere in my program. Where is it?

The only place I can think of is main+14. I run 405064 into a hexadecimal to ascii and utf converter, neither of which produced "test". Does that mean 0x405064 is the address where the "test" string is stored? If so, why is it in a random address rather than one relative to the main function? Or is text encoded differently in memory and my hex to ascii converter is pointless?

Also, if the stack is allocated 16 bytes, why is the string stored in [esp]? Aren't characters 1 byte long, and therefore the string should be stored in [ebp-4]?

Comment: Yes you are correct. `0x405064` is the address of the string, but that is in a different section that you did not dump. Would not make sense to disassemble, but you can view the data. It's stored at `[esp]` because that's going to be the first argument to `printf`.

Comment: In addition to what @Jester said: 1) `printf` is in a standard C library, which is in a library file (not a DLL file), and the code for it is linked into your executable. Code in a DLL file is loaded at runtime. 2)  `printf` is a terrible function to try to work out in disassembly because it accepts a variable number of arguments after the first one depending on the format string (specified in the first argument).

Comment: The code for `printf` is only linked into your executable if you use static linking. Normally it is in a DLL/shared object, e.g. `libc.so` and it is loaded at runtime.

Comment: @Jester How would I go about dumping that section with objdump or gdb?

Comment: gdb can show it to you using `x/s 0x405064`. Or `objdump -s -j .rodata` assuming your compiler put it into that section, could also be `.data`. Alternatively pass an address range, e.g. `objdump -s --start-address=0x405064 --stop-address=0x405069` or similar.

Comment: If you use a better disassembler than objdump/GDB then it would have detected that a string of ascii bytes exists at the address being moved into [esp] and could have labelled the asm with a comment indicating the content of the string at the address 0x405064. I suggest IDA free or radare2 or ghidra